# Python Tkinter Entry Widget not deleting and inserting

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a wordle game and have entries that will take in a single character before moving on to the next entry. As of now, the game is working, but it does not allow for backspace if a mistake was made. I am trying to incorporate that.

```
def pause(event, i):
    p = StringVar()
    window.bind(event, lambda e : p.set(inner[i].get()))
    window.wait_variable(p)

i = 0
while i < 30:
    inner[i].focus_set()
    pause("<KeyRelease>", i)
    if inner[i].get() == "":
        i -= 1
        inner[i].delete(0, END)
        word = word[:-1]
        continue
    word += inner[i].get()
```

inner is a list of all the entries. I wasn't sure if there was a better way to get the exact keyboard input (I tried to download and import keyboard, but that was not working), so I was able to determine that if inner[i].get() == "" that means that the input was a backspace. I wanted to increment i by negative one if this was the case so that the entry in focus would be the previous entry. I would then want to delete what was in that entry and insert a new character by continuing through the loop. However, the entry is not being deleted at all.